# alternative to using shell32.dll

Tags: vba, printing, trojan

Can a file printing routine be written not using the word "Shell32.dll" as using this within my protected VBA within an XLSB file is flagging that the Excel file contains a Trojan related script and is not able to email or download the excel file.

Existing code causing the Trojan error message.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Const SW_HIDE = 0

Sub PrintFile(ByVal strFilePath As String)

    Dim retVal As Long
    retVal = ShellExecute(0, "Print", strFilePath, 0, 0, SW_HIDE)

    If retVal < 32 Then
        MsgBox "An error occured...Could not print"
        With Application
           .EnableEvents = True
           .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What's flagging your xlsb as a trojan? Do you get the same message if you save as a macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm)?

Answer (score 0):

The VBA standard library contains a thin wrapper around that API function, conveniently named `Shell`, in the `VBA.Interaction` module - maybe this can work for you?

```
result = Shell("print " & path, vbHide)
```